# Developing a Module for IIS7

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I've been working on a module for IIS7.  I want to intercept requests from a specific browser.  This is only in dev, but right now my code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyModule : IHttpModule
    {

        #region IHttpModule Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(OnPreRequestHandlerExecute);
        }

        #endregion


        public void OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;

            string useragent = "AGENT: " + request.Headers["User-Agent"];

            throw new HttpException(403, useragent);
            // stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test this, but despite reading NUMEROUS articles on adding it to IIS7, I can't seem to get it working.

Examples:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/366/developing-iis-70-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework/
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/269/how-to-create-a-simple-iis-manager-module/

I've got the module strongly named, signed, you name it.  I can't seem to get it to show up under Managed Modules for IIS.

If someone who has experience in this area could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!  The code is very incomplete and I don't expect it to be perfect, but just to get it working under IIS7 right now would be a huge step forward.

Thanks!

Comment: You can simply drop the MyNameSpace.dll file in the bin folder, and then reference it like this in the <system.webserver><modules> section of the web.config:<add name="MyModuleName" type="MyNamespace.MyModule, MyNamespace" preCondition="managedHandler" />

Comment: @Tchami: I set this up in web.config and now it's throwing an error: "Server Error in '/' Application. This type of page is not served. "  The page loads when I remove web.config.  Is the error with the config or the module and how do I correct it?  Thanks!!!

Comment: @Tchami: Can you add your comment as a question?  I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply drop the MyNameSpace.dll file in the bin folder, and then reference it like this in the  section of the web.config:

```
<add name="MyModuleName" type="MyNamespace.MyModule, MyNamespace" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```